# Android Dynamic Spinner

Tags: android

```
 private void createSpinner() {
ll.addView(s);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbs.getReadableDatabase();     
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Test where password = 'S'"; 
    final Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL, null); 
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    final int l = cursor.getCount();
    array_spinner = new String[l];
int i = 0;
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
  array_spinner[i]= cursor.getString(1);
   i ++;
 }
    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
    cursor.close();
ll.addView(submit);
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {

        }
     }});
}
```

In this code i want the user to select the value in the spinner which is sent from the database. And then when the user clicks on the submit button i want that value selected to be saved to the database...i am wondering what the selected spinner option function is...is there a adapter.selected() r checked or a spinner.selected function available? hope i am explaining it correctly thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()`

Comment: i have tried that and it sort of works but the app keeps going around in a loop because the spinner is always selected, is there a way to have a blank or unselected option at the beginning of the spinner, because when the spinner shows on the screen it is always going to have something selected

Comment: Right now u r dynamically adding from db to an array. You may make the first element of the array as null and from 2nd position onwards u can add data to array from db...

Comment: array_spinner[0] = "Please select from below";   If i set the first option to this and then the rest from the cursor, it stop running correctly and doesnt display anything in the spinner and doesnt show the submit button

Comment: I have tried that and for some reason it isnt working, the spinner shows up blank and the following code i belive doesnt run

Comment: how it worked? what change u made? Please write that also so that if others face the issue, it will be helpful.